# Calculate the mean at a given site if weeks match across years

Tags: r

My data are as follows:

```
year week site prop 
2020 3    A    0.2  
2020 3    B    0.1    
2020 4    A    0.3  
2020 4    B    0.5  
2021 3    A    0.9  
2021 3    B    0.7  
2021 4    A    0.1  
2021 4    B    0.8  
2021 5    A    0.1  
2021 5    B    0.8
```

I would like to calculate the mean of prop across years, within the same week and for the same site. For example, the prop value at site A in week 3 is 0.2 and 0.9 in 2020 and 2021, respectively. The mean of these two values is 0.55.
If there is a week in one year, but not the other, the output under mean would be NA. My desired output is as follows:

```
year week site prop mean
2020 3    A    0.2  0.55
2020 3    B    0.1  0.4  
2020 4    A    0.3  0.2
2020 4    B    0.5  0.065
2021 3    A    0.9  0.55
2021 3    B    0.7  0.4
2021 4    A    0.1  0.2
2021 4    B    0.8  0.065
2021 5    A    0.1  NA
2021 5    B    0.8  NA
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: please share your data as code instead of formatted tables. You can use `dput(data.frame.name)`

Comment: `library(dplyr); df %>% group_by(week, site) %>% mutate(mean = mean(prop))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the `dplyr::group_by()` and summarise approach:

```
library(dplyr)

data_frame %>% group_by(week, site) %>% summarise(mean = mean(prop))
```

to get the NA values I would just add rows to your data frame where prop is set to NA:

```
year week site prop 
2020 3    A    0.2  
2020 3    B    0.1    
2020 4    A    0.3  
2020 4    B    0.5 
2020 5    A    NA 
2020 5    B    NA 
2021 3    A    0.9  
2021 3    B    0.7  
2021 4    A    0.1  
2021 4    B    0.8  
2021 5    A    0.1  
2021 5    B    0.8
```